# Don't know why I'm getting a foreign constraint error in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I've created these two tables in SQLite:

```
CREATE TABLE CONFLUENCE_LINKS (
    longLink        TEXT NOT NULL
                         PRIMARY KEY,
    shortLink       TEXT NOT NULL
                         DEFAULT [short link not found yet],
    dateLastUpdated TEXT NOT NULL
                         DEFAULT [last updated date will be added soon]
);

CREATE TABLE LOG_CONFLUENCE_PAGES_TO_FIX (
    shortLink             TEXT    NOT NULL
                                  PRIMARY KEY,
    dateChecked           TEXT    NOT NULL,
    numDaysMissingAltText INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (
        shortLink
    )
    REFERENCES CONFLUENCE_LINKS (shortLink) ON DELETE CASCADE
                                            ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE CONFLUENCE_PAGES_MISSING_ALT_TEXT (
    shortLink       TEXT NOT NULL
                         PRIMARY KEY,
    pageName        TEXT NOT NULL,
    hasImages       TEXT NOT NULL
                         DEFAULT FALSE,
    hasAltText      TEXT NOT NULL
                         DEFAULT FALSE,
    imageNamesLinks TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (
        shortLink
    )
    REFERENCES CONFLUENCE_LINKS (shortLink) ON DELETE CASCADE
                                            ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Then I added a row to CONFLUENCE_LINKS:

```
INSERT INTO CONFLUENCE_LINKS (longLink) VALUES ("espn.com")
```

Then I try to remove this row and commit this change using the GUI buttons in SQLiteStudio.   SQL won't remove this row; I get this error instead:

```
Error while deleting row from table CONFLUENCE_LINKS: foreign key mismatch - "CONFLUENCE_PAGES_MISSING_ALT_TEXT" referencing "CONFLUENCE_LINKS"
```

I'd kinda understand getting this error if I was deleting data from CONFLUENCE_LINKS (parent table) that was actually getting referenced in CONFLUENCE_PAGES_MISSING_ALT_TEXT (child table).  But CONFLUENCE_PAGES_MISSING_ALT_TEXT contains no data!  So I don't understand why I'm getting this error now.

I'm using Linux Mint 20 btw, if that helps anything.

**EDIT**

My bad for forgetting to include one of the key table definitions.  I've added it above.

Comment: What's the definition of `CONFLUENCE_PAGES_MISSING_ALT_TEXT`?

Comment: *I'd kinda understand getting this error if I was deleting data from CONFLUENCE_LINKS* but you are deleting from `CONFLUENCE_LINKS`. Also, what is `CONFLUENCE_PAGES_MISSING_ALT_TEXT`?

Comment: My bad for forgetting to include one of the key table definitions. I've added it above.

Comment: It works fine for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3cffb01e8c4884730713dc152bc027eb

Comment: Thanks for referencing dbfiddle.uk @forpas .  I had never heard of that before.  I definitely bookmarked that.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm unable to replicate the error too, if I run the DELETE statement from the Linux terminal:

```
$sqlite3 NAME_OF_DB

sqlite> DELETE FROM CONFLUENCE_LINKS WHERE longLink = 'espn.com';
```

But I do get the error if I delete this row using the GUI buttons in SQLiteStudio (v3.3.3).  At first I thought the issue was with this db manager, so I downloaded and tested [a bunch of other db managers](https://medevel.com/13-sqlite-database-clients-managers/).   The error persisted with these other db managers too, which suggests the issue is likely with my code.

---

Turns out I needed to add an INDEX table too.

Here's that third INDEX table:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UX_CONFLUENCE_LINKS_SHORTLINK ON CONFLUENCE_LINKS(shortLink)
```

Everything is working now!!!

Below are some references that helped me:

- [Answer from a StackExchange post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/195722)
- [SQLite documentation on db indexes](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes)
- [W3Schools page on SQL UNIQUE constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)